# Spring: Injected field is null

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring (non-boot) application in which I'm trying to autowire a field into a class as such:

```
@Route("login")
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout {

    private LoginOverlay login;

    @Autowired
    private UiSecurityService uiSecurityService;
    
    public LoginView() {
    createContents();
    }
    
    private void createContents() {
    // create Layout
    }

    private void onLoginPressed(LoginEvent e) {
    // handle login
    }
}
```

However, `UiSecurityService` is always `null`.

`UiSecurityService` should be annoted correctly:

```
@Component
public class UiSecurityService {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    public LoginResult login(String username, String password) {
    // handle login
    }

}
```

Also, the `@ComponentScan` annotation is (as far as I know) set correctly as well:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ SomeConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class })
@ImportResource("classpath:/path/to/config/*-context.xml")
@ComponentScan("parent.package.where.beans.are.located")
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
}
```

What am I missing? I have tried injecting `UiSecurityService` via a setter, same result. I can't use constructor injection because then vaadin throws an exception.

Comment: I have no idea what the issue is, but the example given in the Vaadin docs uses constructor injection: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/integrations/spring/tutorial-spring-routing

Comment: @tgdavies Yeah I usually use that as well, but when working with Vaadin I always used it with spring boot. Trying it in this application resulted in an exception telling me it requires a no-args constructor which was obviously missing, making me think it's related to this not being a spring boot project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `@Component` in `@Router`.

`@Autowired` spring bean injection can use only in spring bean component and can use only with spring bean component.

If you want to inject spring bean, you must use `@Component` on `LoginView` like below.

```
@Component
@Route("login")
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout {

    private LoginOverlay login;

    @Autowired
    private UiSecurityService uiSecurityService;
    
    public LoginView() {
    createContents();
    }
    
    private void createContents() {
    // create Layout
    }

    private void onLoginPressed(LoginEvent e) {
    // handle login
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sadly it's still now working, even though `@ComponentScan` is set up correctly. Will have to look further into the issue.